# Simple php code for sending Infobip sms to a phone

Tags: php, infobip, infobip-api

I need assistance in sending sms from a form on a website.
I have tried the code below with no success.

```
<?php 
$username = '';
$password = '';

$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$text = urlencode($message);
//Send sms   
private function sendSms(){        
      $posturl='http://api.infobip.com/api/v3/sendsms/plain?user=$username&password=$password&sender=$from&SMSText=$text&GSM=$to'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some logic to call the actual $posturl.

You can check cUrl, or do a simple file_get_contents($posturl);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$username = '';
$password = '';

$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$text = urlencode($message);
//Send sms   
private function sendSms(){        
      $posturl=file('http://api.infobip.com/api/v3/sendsms/plain?user=$username&password=$password&sender=$from&SMSText=$text&GSM=$to'); 
return $posturl;
}
?>
```

It will return the response as  array based on the return response line.

Answer (score 0):

> Infobip API PHP tutorial
>  This is a sample code using curl :)
>    `http://api.infobip.com/api/sendsms/xml";
>           $xmlString = "
>           
>           Your infobip username 
>           infobip password
>           
>           
>           title
>               Your message here 
>           
>           Phone number here
>           
>           
>           ";
>           $fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);
>           $ch = curl_init($postUrl);
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
>           $response = curl_exec($ch);
>           curl_close($ch); ?>`